# Addition symbol keyword Vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, keyword, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to write a Vim syntax file that recognises the addition symbol (`+`) as a keyword.

Here is what I have tried:

```
syn keyword shlKeywords + print
hi def shlKeywords Keyword
```

When I open a file with the associated file extension, `+` is not highlighted, but `print` is. I have tried other symbols, and they also aren't highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Vim user manual](http://www.eandem.co.uk/mrw/vim/usr_doc/doc_a4m.pdf):

> The characters used in a keyword must be in the 'iskeyword' option. If you
>   use another character, the word will never match. Vim doesn't give a warning
>   message for this.

This is what i did:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=+
syn keyword shlKeywords + print
hi def shlKeywords Keyword
```